# Complex differentiable function is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a differentiable function such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $f=0$..

I know one uniqueness result namely if $f=0$ on an open set then $f=0$

Could not think of any useful result..

Comment: Hint: $f$ is zero on a set that contains a limit point

Comment: Show $f(0)=0$ and use the fact that you have a set with a limit point on which $f\equiv0$.

Comment: See [an improvement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement)

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 : I do not see how your comment helps anyhow :O

Comment: Use Identity theorem...Do you know this theorem?

Comment: @S.Panja What open set precisely do you see in the OP that we're given the function is zero on?

Comment: I think what i have stated is the identity theorem... $f=0$ on an open set then $f=0$ but here i do not see why this $f$ has to be zero on an open set.. It is just said that it is zero on a countable set

Comment: @Mark : That was useful. Thanks

Comment: @cello Please see Henry W.'s comment.

Comment: @HenryW. : That was useful. Thanks

Comment: @Clayton : Yes Yes i got it..